# Version control with python. Git merge analog

Tags: python, python-3.x, git, git-merge

I have two versions of one project with different features.
To merge versions I can use GitHub or Bitbucket, but is it possible to make this with some python library?

Comment: Can't you do it with git on the command line? What's the reason you do it on GitHub or BitBucket?

Comment: GitHub and Bitbucket aren't version control systems (VCS) - they're just websites. You can use Git (this is different from GitHub) or any other VCS or just merge everything manually. If you _really_ need a Python library, you could try [GitPython](https://github.com/gitpython-developers/GitPython), but it still uses git under the hood.